# Is this supposed to be the "Resolute Desk"?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

In *The Expanse* series, season 4 episode 10, 37 minutes in, Avasarala is sitting at a desk which looks to be the famed "[Resolute Desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolute_desk)" used by current day U.S. presidents. On closer comparison to images of the actual "Resolute Desk", the *Expanse* desk looks very similar but there are several easily spotted differences (aside from the missing center panel commissioned by FDR to hide his braces and presumed to have been later removed.)

Is the desk in *The Expanse* used by U.N. General Secretary supposed to be the same desk from U.S. history or is it just a big wood desk?

[image]

Comment: A picture of the desk in the episode would help. The one I found online is definitely not a copy or recreation of the Resolute Desk (carving and structural elements are different), so I'd say it's meant to just be a big wood desk.

Comment: @Lexible Thanks for adding the image to my post. I wanted to get a screen capture of the show's desk but couldn't access Prime account.  I had heard that a second similar desk was constructed from the wood of the HMS Resolute. There is indeed a second desk from HMS Resolute wood... but is completely different in style (open bottom framework, taller, overall much smaller).

Comment: Oh! I did not add the image (I think @DoscoJones did). My contributions were the link to the Wikipedia article, and some minor orthographic editing. :) <3

Comment: @DoscoJones thanks!

Comment: @BradV No worries

Answer (score 9):

It does not look at all the same, even accounting for the middle panel.

[image: Obama at Resolute desk]

It's not the same desk.

Comment: There could be some inspiration there. It's not some futuristic sci-fi desk, it is carved wood and about as ornate as the real thing. But yes, obviously not the same and not intended to be the same.